# backing up postgres on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql

Ok, I'm quite new to this server administration stuff. I have set up an ec2 instance running my website. I'm running everything on a single machine - node.js & postgres. What is the best way to backup my postgres db?

Thanks for your h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest and recommended ways is to use *pg_dump*. It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently.

Script *pg_dump* to offload dumps to S3 bucket. Setup the script to be run using crontab on a hourly basis.

Comment: how do you get pg_dump to offload dumps to s3?

Comment: Have pg_dump dump the backup sql. Use scripts like s3curl.pl ( http://aws.amazon.com/code/128 ) or s3cmd ( http://s3tools.org/s3cmd ) to push the dump to S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pgAdmin to backup your databases:

http://www.pgadmin.org/

It's very easy. Login to localhost or hostname if remote. After setting up your connection in pgAdmin, goto Server Groups->Servers->PostgreSQL 9.0 (localhost:5432)->database. Drop-down menu and select backup. Enter filename. Hit OK. Backup done.